# copying extracted date into row, as long as date does not change - R 3.1.1 / Windows

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying for some time to get my head around a copy problem. I am trying to extract the date from a data frame and copy it in a new row as long as the date does not change.

I found a few discussions on different problems, but I was not getting the right results in ifelse and for loops.

The data is from the following site : http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2015&MONTH=01&FROM=0100&TO=0312&STNM=VECC)

data is cleaned up by removing not footer information and added column date, VECCsample2 is a sample from the link above that I used

```
data <- read.table('./VECCsample2.txt', sep = "", na.strings = "99999", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# removing unneeded rows
data <- data[data$V1 != "Station", ]
data <- data[data$V1 != "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------", ]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Showalter",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Lifted",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "LIFT",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "SWEAT",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "K",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Cross",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Vertical",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Observation",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Totals",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Convective",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "CAPE",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "CINS",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Equilibrum",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Level",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "LFCT",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Bulk",]
data <- data[data$V6 != "Condensation",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Mean",]
data <- data[data$V6 != "thickness:",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "Precipitable",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "hPa",]
data <- data[data$V1 != "PRES",]

# renaming headers
names(data) <- c("PRES", "HGHT", "TEMP", "DEWP", "RELH", "MIXR", "DRCT", "SKNT", "THTA", "THTE", "THTV") 
# adding empty date column 
data$date <- 0
```

an example of the data

```
row.names   PRES    HGHT    TEMP    DEWP    RELH    MIXR    DRCT    SKNT    THTA    THTE    THTV    date
1   1   42809.0 VECC    Calcutta    Observations    at  00Z 01  January 2014            0
2   5   1004.0  6   28.2    26.0    88  21.64   180 3   301.0   365.1   304.9   0
3   6   1000.0  42  27.2    24.2    84  19.45   180 4   300.4   357.7   303.8   0
4   7   978.0   239 25.4    22.5    84  17.85   180 11  300.4   353.0   303.6   0
5   8   960.0   403 23.8    21.0    84  16.61   215 17  300.4   349.3   303.4   0
6   9   950.0   496 30.4    18.4    49  14.22   235 21  308.0   351.4   310.7   0
7   120 42809.0 VECC    Calcutta    Observations    at  00Z 02  January 2014            0
8   124 1005.0  6   26.2    23.3    84  18.30   45  2   298.9   352.5   302.2   0
9   125 1000.0  50  25.0    20.5    76  15.43   60  6   298.1   343.2   300.9   0
10  126 974.0   282 23.4    20.6    84  15.95   108 14  298.8   345.4   301.6   0
11  127 965.0   364 23.5    20.8    85  16.35   125 17  299.7   347.7   302.6   0
```

I am trying to extract the date (01 January 2014) and copy it in the date column. The 1 January 2014 needs to be copied until the separator "VECC" is read. The output should look like

```
row.names   PRES    HGHT    TEMP    DEWP    RELH    MIXR    DRCT    SKNT    THTA    THTE    THTV    date
1   1   42809.0 VECC    Calcutta    Observations    at  00Z 01  January 2014            0
2   5   1004.0  6   28.2    26.0    88  21.64   180 3   301.0   365.1   304.9   01 January 2014
3   6   1000.0  42  27.2    24.2    84  19.45   180 4   300.4   357.7   303.8   01 January 2014
4   7   978.0   239 25.4    22.5    84  17.85   180 11  300.4   353.0   303.6   01 January 2014
5   8   960.0   403 23.8    21.0    84  16.61   215 17  300.4   349.3   303.4   01 January 2014
6   9   950.0   496 30.4    18.4    49  14.22   235 21  308.0   351.4   310.7   01 January 2014
7   120 42809.0 VECC    Calcutta    Observations    at  00Z 02  January 2014            0
8   124 1005.0  6   26.2    23.3    84  18.30   45  2   298.9   352.5   302.2   02 January 2014
9   125 1000.0  50  25.0    20.5    76  15.43   60  6   298.1   343.2   300.9   02 January 2014
10  126 974.0   282 23.4    20.6    84  15.95   108 14  298.8   345.4   301.6   02 January 2014
11  127 965.0   364 23.5    20.8    85  16.35   125 17  299.7   347.7   302.6   02 January 2014
```

I have tried different options with if, ifelse, for loops, which did not did what I would like
The one that provided the best option is :

```
pattern = "VECC"
name_row <- grep(pattern, data$HGHT)
name_row_date <- data[name_row,]
if (grep(pattern, data$HGHT)) data$date <- name_row_date$DRCT
```

or

```
for (index in 1:nrow(data)) { 
    row = data[index, ] 

    if (row[index,3] == "VECC") {
        date <- row[row$SKNT,]
        data$date <- "NA"
    }
    if (row[index,3] != "VECC")
        data$date <- date
}
```

Did somebody have a similar exercise or a hint on how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exploit the html tags in the document to do the following, to get the dates out.

```
library(XML)
file<- "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2015&MONTH=01&FROM=0100&TO=0312&STNM=VECC"
wx<- htmlTreeParse(file,useInternalNodes=T)
heads<- xpathSApply(xmlRoot(wx),"//h2",xmlValue)
h<-unlist(strsplit(heads," Observations at "))
sounding.dates<- strptime(h[!seq_along(h)%%2],"%HZ %d %b %Y",tz="GMT")
```

This gives a vector of dates corresponding to the tabular soundings.

The station identification is also in the `heads` vector.

Comment: Thanks, when I am running the wx <- htmlTreeParse row with the useInternalNodes=T, the wx is empty and I am getting the following error. Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "NULL". Is there something that I didn't set properly?

Comment: Did you get back any warnings or errors from htmlTreeParse? Did you set the `file` variable to the URL?

Comment: from the htmTreeParse no errors. I ran the getXMLerrors and I am getting back '"Document is empty\n"'. In setting the file to URL, you mean as set above, right?

Comment: I re-ran the code, even changing a few parameters in the URL to make sure it was not somehow using a cache of this document.  The code in my answer seems to work just fine. Are you having connectivity issues? Maybe your firewall is blocking R?

Comment: thanks! it works, indeed a firewall issue (as you mentioned). The output provides me with the dates that the data is available, but how can I copy these dates behind the rows with measurements? The aim is to analyze weather differences per day.

Comment: You have a few options for that. One is to further exploit the HTML structure, recognizing the tables are tagged as `<pre>`. So each `<h2>` corresponds to the `<pre>` in order.  You may also find the tables of data have a consistent number of rows, which would mean you can simply use `rep` with the `each` argument.  A third option is to read the data using `readLines` and append the corresponding date to each line you read.

Comment: Thanks! I will check the options.

Comment: I have tried to explore the XML options a bit more (actually tried all of them), but unfortunately I was not able to get the result I am looking for...  Going with the XML (`body <- xpathSApply(xmlRoot(wx),"//pre",xmlValue)`), I have the following steps defined: 1) delete every 2nd row (as it does not contain the data that I want with `cleaned <- data.frame((unlist(body), nrow=length(body), byrow=T))`, 2) copy the date (sounding.dates) before each "/n" and 3) making a data frame out of it by splitting on "/n" and by "  ". thanks in advance